# Problem with getting clear and continuous contours opencv

Tags: opencv, contour

I am using contour detection but the contour I am getting is not continuous, how can I detect the continuous contour of the image. Here is the output:

**Output Image with contours**
[image: Output Image with contours]

The output what I want is something like this which I got by using my algorithm:

**Input Image**
[image: Input Image]

Here I am using `cv2.findCountour` without using hierarchy which is also obtained from it. If possible please use the same.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please share the code as well with which you got your result.

Comment: Share a blank input image as well so that we can test it on our machines as well.